# Find integer $n$ where $1+\frac{n}{10} < \alpha < 1+\frac{n+1}{10}$

Tags: graphing-functions, continuity

On first look, doesn't any number suffice? For example, if I let $n=1$ then $$1+\frac{1}{10} < \alpha < 1+\frac{2}{10}$$ is valid right? Tho, I think the question is asking in the context of the rest of the question? Am at part iv

[image]

I don't really get the reasoning behind the answer tho

[image]

How does the pieces fall into place? Why the expression for $g(x)$. How do I get the seemingly arbitrary numbers 1.7 and 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for $g(x)$ comes from (iii).  Apparently $\alpha \ln \alpha - \ln(1+\alpha) = 0$, so $g(\alpha) = 0$.  As for how to get the numbers 1.7 and 1.8:  The question sort of indicates that you'll probably find something fairly near 1, so I guess just trying values $g(1+\frac{n}{10})$ for $n$ from $0$ to $10$ until you get a change of sign could be expected to work.  There's probably a better way.

As for your first question, yes, of course it's in the context of the rest of the question.  Otherwise what is $\alpha$?  How could you claim that any $n$ works, without knowing what $\alpha$ is?